# swagger page showing fix_this. How to fix it

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, swagger

I am doing spring boot + swagger for the first time and could see the swagger page. Its beautiful. But instead of the title I see fix_this.

I see that I have coded the @API annotation..

```
@Api(value = "CRM Services", description = "CRM Operations")
```

So can anybody help me on this one please?[image]

Comment: Pls try putting the Path and Api value as the same string. Without the space, and with a forward slash. Maybe like this - @Path(value="/crm")
@Api(value="/crm")

Comment: Adding a / in the front isn't working

Comment: Even after removing the white space?

Comment: Yes. It doesnt work even after that

Comment: Have you added the @Path annotation as well?

Comment: I am sorry. Do you know the fully qualified name of the path annotation. I see a lot of package names

Comment: its javax.ws.rs.Path